# Bottom Navgiation Icons showing as squares in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying out React Native app development using Expo.

I found a few very interesting frameworks, like react-native-paper. I'm trying to use their [Bottom Navigation example, see the "Try this example on Snack" link](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/bottom-navigation.html) they provide.

However, when I run the example, none of my devices show any icons, just white squares where they are supposed to be. Tested out on iOS and Android.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';

const MusicRoute = () => <Text>Music</Text>;

const AlbumsRoute = () => <Text>Albums</Text>;

const RecentsRoute = () => <Text>Recents</Text>;

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'music', title: 'Music', icon: 'queue-music' },
      { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', icon: 'album' },
      { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', icon: 'history' },
    ],
  };

  _handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({ index });

  _renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    music: MusicRoute,
    albums: AlbumsRoute,
    recents: RecentsRoute,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        navigationState={this.state}
        onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I tried Googling around but not getting much help. Tried manually importing the icons, but no luck.

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

[image]

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far. or you just tried the example in the BottomNavigation tutorial ?

Comment: @Sateesh Like I said, I'm using the tutorial snack @ Expo and it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `react-native-paper` with `yarn`. And install these commands below one after another.

```
yarn add react-native-paper

yarn add react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs react-native-paper

yarn add react-native-vector-icons

react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Stop the current project which is running already and rerun `react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone XR"` only if it is not working.

[image]

**Edit:**

If you use Expo, you don't need to install vector icons. But you will need to make sure that your .babelrc includes `babel-preset-expo`:

```
{
  "presets": ["expo"]
}
```

If you don't use React Native Paper app, you should also add `react-native-paper/babel` to your `.babelrc` to avoid importing the whole library. See the [Getting Started guide](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/getting-started.html) for more information.

Comment: So the icons are not supposed to be working on the Expo site? I'm using https://snack.expo.io

Comment: Thanks! Creating a file called `.babelrc` and using your snippet works. So strange that they don't mention this in the preview.

Comment: Yes they didn't. I also faced the same issue when I was trying the bottom navigation. After lots of R&D came to know that .babelsc is missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. close running packager
2. run `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`
3. and `run react-native start --reset-cache`
4. Finally use `react-native run-ios`

Try running `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

If RN < 0.29, `run rnpm link react-native-vector-icons`

If RN >= 0.29, `run react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

Also there is a possibility that Paper library again install react-native-vector-icon, and react-native also has it's own vector-icon so, clashed between them. So, also try to remove vector-icon of Paper library.

Thank You!!!

Comment: So the icons are not supposed to be working on the Expo site? I'm using https://snack.expo.io